# Flutter, How to do like this table?

Tags: flutter, datatable, flutter-layout

I need to do the `dataTable` like the style below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Table`, like this:

```
Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Table(
              border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
              children: [
                TableRow(children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Full Name',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('Sarah'),
                  ),
                ]),
                TableRow(children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Email',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('Sarah@gamil.com'),
                  ),
                ])
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

You can find more about Table widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Flutter has a Table class for this (but you can also do it using simple Row + Column combo).

Here's the link to the Table docs: [Flutter Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)

```
Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
          children: [
            TableRow(children: [
              Text('Cell 1'),
              Text('Cell 2'),
              Text('Cell 3'),
            ]),
            TableRow(children: [
              Text('Cell 4'),
              Text('Cell 5'),
              Text('Cell 6'),
            ])
          ],
        ),
      )
```